# Redirect with time to next page after clcik on button

Tags: jquery

Hi i have this code to redirect to cart after click. But redirect is quicker than put to the cart. I need 1s delay before redirecting. Can you help me?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add-to-cart-button').click(function(){
      window.location= "cart/";
  });
```

});

Comment: Looks like an XY problem.  What do you use for "put to cart"?  Should be able to hook a callback into *that* call.

Comment: Perhaps it's the right time to take a look at AJAX `$.ajax` and at the success `.done` callback

Comment: But if you insist, then you'll find that 1s may not always be enough, even changing to eg 10s may not be enough in some cases:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout - `setTimeout(function() { window.location = ".."; }, 1000)`

Comment: i need someone this, but i dont know how:
  setTimeout("location.href = '/cart';", 1500);

Comment: @SnipermMan how is your backend route for `cart/` structured? You use Node.js (Express)? PHP? Python?

Comment: @SnipermMan how does your HTML looks like? Do you use `<a>`, `<button>`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setTimeout` to wait for `1.5` seconds before your perform a redirect to your cart page.

Run snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-to-cart-button').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location = "cart/";
      console.log('Redirected')
    }, 1500)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-to-cart-button">Add to Cart</button>
```